# Canceling changing color on refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

I'am working with chartjs and i get new colors every time i refresh the page. i want to have random colors but those colors needed to be fixed so they will not change after i refresh or reload the page.
this the function i'am working with :

```js
getRandomRgb() {
    var num = Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random());
 
    var r = num >> 16;
    var g = (num >> 8) & 255;
    var b = num & 255;
    return "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
  }
```

this is where i used

```
this.currentResponseItems.forEach((x) => {
            x.Items.forEach((z) => {
              if (!colorMap[z.Description]) {
                colorMap[z.Description] = this.getRandomColor();
              }
              console.log(z.Description, " : ", colorMap[z.Description]);
              z["phaseId"] = x.Id;
              let zData = [];

              let number = array.indexOf(z.phaseId);
              if (z.Number != 0) {
                zData[number] = z.Number;

                this.barChartData.push({
                  data: zData,
                  stack: x.Id,
                  label: z.Description,
                  fill: false,
                  grouped: true,
                  idStatoAffiliazione: x.Id,
                  channelID: z.Id,
                  backgroundColor: colorMap[z.Description],
                  hoverBackgroundColor: colorMap[z.Description],
                  pointBackgroundColor: colorMap[z.Description],
                  pointBorderColor:colorMap[z.Description],
                  pointHoverBackgroundColor:colorMap[z.Description],
                  pointHoverBorderColor: colorMap[z.Description],
                
                });
```

And this the chartjs in html :

```
 <div class="container-chart cursor-pointer" fxLayout="row" *ngIf="barChartData.length > 0" fxLayoutGap="20px">
                <canvas baseChart fxFlex="100" [chartType]="'horizontalBar'" [datasets]="barChartData" [options]="barChartOptions" [labels]="barChartLabels" [colors]="graphColors" ></canvas>
                <!-- <graph-legend fxFlex="20" [configs]="graphLegendConfig"></graph-legend> -->
            </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the function you're using, but we still need to see it being used. Update the code to be a [mcve]

Comment: Can you add also the chart configuration you are using the function and which options?

Comment: You could save the color in a cookie or localStorage. And only set the color new, when there isn't a saved color.

Comment: I updated the question as you asked thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist the color on refresh without the use of a server, you'll have to store it in the browser of the user. For example, you can do this by storing it in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Using this, your function could look like this:

```js
function getRandomRgb(colorId) {
    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(`randomRgb-${colorId}`)) return localStorage.getItem(`randomRgb-${colorId}`)

    var num = Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random());
    var r = num >> 16;
    var g = (num >> 8) & 255;
    var b = num & 255;
    var randomRgb = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";

    localStorage.setItem(`randomRgb-${colorId}`, randomRgb)
    return randomRgb
}
```

To generate a color for a certain colorId in your example, you could do:

```
getRandomRgb(colorMap[z.Description])
```

Another way would be to store your entire colorMap in localStorage, instead of specific colors.

Comment: thank you for your reply ,but this one aleays storing only one color in the local storage

Comment: You can alter the function by giving it a parameter with a colorId, so you can store multiple colors in local storage.   Edit: I've updated my answer with an example, let me know if this helps.

Comment: yeah it is now stored with multiple colors but how i push that data into the chart

Comment: the problemes still persisting i had some data in the local storage but i always have new colors

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming that colorMap is your array where you have all colors, you should save this array in **localStorage** but you should **stringify** it first and then change your  if statement in something like this

```
// save into local storage use this when your array is completly generated
localStorage.setItem("colorMap", JSON.stringify(colorMap));
```

your statement should looks like this

```
//check if there is colors saved in localStorage 
if(!localStorage.getItem("colorMap")){
  // generate new random values
} else { 
  // retrieve your saved array from local storage
  colorMap = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("colorMap"));
}
```